# Why i am getting the of Google Authorization from urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob?

Tags: oauth, redirect-uri

I am making a google authorization login screen to verify my web app for uploading videos to YouTube directly from anywhere. My All code is according to the google Authorization token manual, but I am still getting this error regarding the Redirect_URI. Barely I can understand this error, some gave me its solution. Which I am posting in answer section.

The given image is my error type. I am getting this type of error after google announced its discontinuing OOB support from October 2022.

([image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error solution is Changing the REDIRECT_URI to Your own token copy webpage or directly verifying your page.
Example:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=www.givenwebpg.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

here new `redirect Uri=www.givenwebpg.com`. change your old Uri with this your problem will be solved.